# How can I check if a var is equal a translated label?

Tags: posts, translation

In my plugin, I can publish a custom post.

When I click on the "Publish" button, I have this data

**$_POST**

```
 Array
 (
   [foo_title] => test

   [foo_price] =>
   ...
   [save] => Publier
)
```

As we can see `$_POST['save']` is translated in french. In my php file, I would like to do a check on this translated label like this :

**PHP File**

```
 if( $_POST["save"] === __( 'Publish' ) ){
    //do something
 }
```

But this code does not work because the output of `__( 'Publish' )` is still *Publish*.

How can I do it ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the text domain too. Assuming that you have the proper `.mo` and `.po` file, and loaded the text domain successfully:

```
 if( $_POST["save"] === __( 'Publish', 'text-domain' ) ){
    //do something
 }
```

But this is not generally a good idea. You should do your checks based on something more certain, not a string that can be changed anytime.

Comment: Normally, the domain is the default one but I did with my plugin domain as well before. That does not work for me. Did you test it ?